# Meta box image field size

Tags: wordpress, image-size, meta-boxes

I'm using Custom metaboxes and fields for Wordpress and I have added image field.

At the frontend I can print image, but I'm not able to add apply image size for it.

In my module I have set CMB field:

```
array(
    'name' => __('Image', 'cmb'),
    'desc' => __('Upload an image or enter a URL.', 'cmb'),
    'id' => $prefix.
    'image',
    'type' => 'file',
    'allow' => array('url', 'attachment'),
),
```

For testing in single.php file I have:

```
global $post;
$image = get_post_meta($post->ID, "_cmb_image", true);
```

This works for printing image in full size:

```
<img src="<?php echo $image; ?>" alt="" />
```

I have tried different ways to print image in certain size which is set in theme functions.php.

For example tried this:

```
<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( get_post_meta( get_the_id(), '_cmb_image', true ), 'thumbnail', false, array( 'class' => 'vert-align-mid' ) ); ?>
```

And this:

```
<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $image, 'thumbnail' ); ?>
```

This aren't working and I'm getting empty value. Any help how to print image in custom size?

Comment: wp_get_attachment_image ( int $attachment_id, string|array $size = 'thumbnail', bool $icon = false, string|array $attr = '' ).. pass attachment id instead of image object

Comment: Could you please provide example code referring mine examples? Not getting it work with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution for this. CMB field type will store ID also. It is stored: `$id . '_id'`. So in my case it will be `_cmb_image_id`.

Add these to template file.

```
<?php image = wp_get_attachment_image( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_cmb_image_id', 1 ), 'thumbnail' ); ?>
```

After this echo image:

```
<?php echo $image; ?>
```

Comment: what if their are multiple images?

Answer (score 0):

From this code you are getting image object :

```
$image = get_post_meta($post->ID, "_cmb_image", true);
```

Now retrieve the image ID from this object and pass to below function :

`$image->ID` is only an example , it must be what you are getting in that object.

```
wp_get_attachment_image ( int $image->ID, string|array $size = 'thumbnail', bool $icon = false, string|array $attr = '' )
```

Comment: If there are multiple images then what should we do because with the help of this we can get only one image.